# Why sometimes Gmail let me add automatically an icalendar file and sometimes no?

Tags: email, gmail, icalendar, gmail-api

I'm working on an app that provides to the user a .ics (iCalendar file) with some events. This file is sent through email and I have realised that sometimes gmail let you to add automatically and sometimes no. Somebody knows why this is happening? 
My ics file with 9 events is:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  1 de Màquines Elèctriques
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160425T160000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160425T180000
LOCATION:Etseib B-B PL-1
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  1 de Màquines Elèctriques
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  2 de Màquines Elèctriques
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160509T160000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160509T180000
LOCATION:Etseib B-B PL-1
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  2 de Màquines Elèctriques
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  3 de Màquines Elèctriques
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160530T160000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160530T180000
LOCATION:Etseib B-B PL-1
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  3 de Màquines Elèctriques
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  4 de Màquines Elèctriques
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160307T160000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160307T180000
LOCATION:Etseib H-5.4
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  4 de Màquines Elèctriques
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  1 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160502T100000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160502T120000
LOCATION:Etseib E-E -1
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  1 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  2 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160509T100000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160509T120000
LOCATION:Etseib E-E -1
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  2 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  3 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160523T100000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160523T120000
LOCATION:Etseib E-E -1
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  3 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  4 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160426T120000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160426T140000
LOCATION:Etseib B-B.5
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  4 de Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Pràctica  1 de Termotècnia
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160309T120000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160309T170000
LOCATION:Etseib H-H 7.56
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Demà Pràctica  1 de Termotècnia
TRIGGER:-PT1H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. Sometimes the event you're sending through email won't work because some of the properties aren't valid. I suggest you to compare the source of a valid invitation with the source of one that does not and you'll probably find the problem.
You can validate the source here : 
http://icalendar.org/validator.html

I ran the code in the validator and it would seem some properties are missing.
**1**. Right after the **VCALENDAR**, there should be the properties  [PRODID](http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-7-3-product-identifier.html) and [VERSION](http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-7-4-version.html). Even if they are mandatory, you only need to inlcude them once in the ics file.

**2**. For every event you create, you need to include a **UID**, which is a unique kind of key, it can be anything as long as it is unique. Also, you will need a **DTSTAMP** which is a date in the same format as the **DTSTART**. You can read about them [here](http://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-6-1-event-component.html).

Also, if perhaps you decide to use recurrent events, you will have 1 event only with a recurrence-rule which you can read about in the same website as the other two.

Hope I could help.

Comment: I have tried to validate my icalendar file and all the code is well written. How did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: The way I mentioned earlier, trial and error since my .ics file was a string sent as an alternate view through email. Perhaps if you told me how you you build the file and the result it gives you I would be able to pinpoint the problem.